# Insert a HTML link next to every word that matches in a sentence for multiple words

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something that I thought would be simple but been stuck on this for a while I want to find all instances of a word in a paragraph and insert a link next to it.

I dont want to use innerHTML and destroy the events. I also dont want to use jQuery ideally pure js.

I am looking to take this paragraph.

```
<p>red this is a sentence I want to change red and I want to change it for all instances the word red</p>
```

Find all index positions of the word red and change it too.

```
<p>red <a href="">Some link</a> this is a sentence I want to change red <a href="">Some link</a> and I want to change it for all instances the word red <a href="">Some link</a></p>
```

So find every instance of the word red grab the index and then insert html not sure it can even be done the way I am doing it, it always only inserts it one time.

I have this so far.

```
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");

[].forEach.call(ps, function(p) {

    const indexes = [...p.innerText.matchAll(new RegExp("red", "gi"))].map(
        (a) => a.index
    );

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "";
    link.innerHTML = `Changed`;

    indexes.forEach((pos) => {
        insertAtStringPos(p, pos, link);
    })

});


function insertAtStringPos(el, pos, insertable) {

    if (!el.children.length) {
        var text = el.outerText;
        var beginning = document.createTextNode(text.substr(0, pos));
        var end = document.createTextNode(text.substr(pos - text.length));

        while (el.hasChildNodes()) {
            el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
        }

        el.appendChild(beginning);
        el.appendChild(insertable);
        el.appendChild(end);
    }
}
```

I grabbed the insertAtStringPos function from another stackoverflow post.

I have an example here: https://jsbin.com/watopeteki/edit?html,js,console,output

Why do it always only insert once?

Comment: what wrong with `innerHTML`? 
html just a text, you may read it from element, change and place back into (carefully).
replace "red" with "red and _anchor_", but avoid replacing "red" in "reduce", it's really may reduce your chances to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be an easier, you need just a split text and by a keyword insert a link.

```
function links() {
  const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');

  return Array.from(ps).reduce((acc, p) => {
    const links = p.querySelectorAll('a');
    const isUpdate = Boolean(links?.length);
    const text = p.innerHTML;

    let index = 0;

    const splitted = text.split(/(red)/gi);
    splitted.forEach((txt) => {
      const el = document.createTextNode(txt);
      acc.appendChild(el);

      if (txt === 'red') {
        let link;
        if (isUpdate) {
          link = links[index++];
          link.href = '';
          link.innerHTML = `Changed after update`;
        } else {
          link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = '';
          link.innerHTML = `Changed`;

          acc.appendChild(link);
        }
      }
    });
    return acc;
  }, document.createElement('p'));
}
const element = links(); // creates links
document.body.appendChild(element);
links(); // updates current links
```

If I understood correct, you need a function which updates your existing links. I have update stackblitz and example, check this out.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-tx9lzv?file=index.html,index.js)

Comment: Thanks is kinda solves my problem but it creates a new element ideally I want it to update the current element so there is not a duplicate. And also it doesnt handle inner html see here https://jsbin.com/watopeteki/4/edit?html,js,output its the same stumbling blocks I was hitting when trying. I did try splitting the html originally at spaces then search the array and replacing and also JSON.stringifying the html splitting editing and then join and JSON.parse no luck ;(

Comment: @user1503606 I have update my answer, check it please

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your code.

1. Your `insertAtStringPos()` function mutates the paragraph element contents, invalidating the remaining indexes in the `indexes` array. Reversing the `indexes` array before looping, and inserting from the end toward the beginning of the text, overcomes this problem.
2. You're passing the `link` element to the `insertAtStringPos()`. This same element gets inserted then moved with each subsequent insertion. Passing a cloned `link` element with each `indexes` iteration solves this problem.
3. [`outerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText), in `var text = el.outerText;`, returns `undefined` in my version of [Firefox (78.15, October 5, 2021)](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/78.15.0/releasenotes/).

---

To [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) for a word in one or more paragraphs, and [`insert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) a [`link node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) after that string, [`loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over each paragraph, search for occurrences of the string, and build an index array. Then loop the index array but first [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) it to start insertion at the end of the string. Also [`copy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the link node before passing to the insertion function, otherwise the link node will simply be moved from one position to the next.

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
const word = "red";
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "";
link.innerHTML = "Changed";

[].forEach.call(ps, function(p) {

    const indexes = [...p.innerText.matchAll(new RegExp(word, "gi"))].map(
        // add word length to position, making sure position is not beyond end of text
        (a) => (p.innerText.length > a.index + word.length)
            ? a.index + word.length // add word length to position
            : p.innerText.length // word is at end of text
    );

    // execute insertion function for each position
    // first reverse index array to start at the end of the text and work towards the beginning
    indexes.reverse().forEach((pos) => {
        // clone node before passing to insertion, otherwise same node simply gets moved
        insertAtStringPos(p, pos, link.cloneNode(true)); // <-- clone node
    })

});


function insertAtStringPos(el, pos, insertable) {

    const text = el.childNodes[0].textContent;
    const beginning = document.createTextNode(text.substr(0, pos) + " "); // text before and including word, plus a space
    const end = document.createTextNode(
        // if position is at end of text, create empty text node
        (text.length > pos)
            ? " " + text.substr(pos - text.length) // a space, and text after word
            : "" // empty text node
    );

    el.removeChild(el.childNodes[0]);
    el.insertBefore(end, el.childNodes[0]);
    el.insertBefore(insertable, el.childNodes[0]);
    el.insertBefore(beginning, el.childNodes[0]);

}
```

```html
<p>red this is a sentence I want to change red and I want to change it for all instances the word red</p>
```